# Apple ipad access Windows network folder shares

Tags: windows-7, ipad

Ipad doesn't seem to have ready usability with [external devices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBr2k1vLojA). How can it view files from a Windows network share like documents in pdf/doc and then audio/video

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install a file viewer app that supports SMB network shares. ezShare Pro from [Antecea Inc.](http://www.antecea.com) looks like it might do what you require.